# The correct way to validate request in asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I've been adding

```
 requestValidationMode="2.0"
```

to my web.config files ever since .net 4.0 came out, but it seems to me that setting the validation mode back to 2 versions prior seems a little silly.  So in .net 4, what is the correct way of managing the request validation?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way, in my opinion, is to let it be and don't mess with it, unless you have a good reason. Default value in version 4.0 is, wait for it, 4.0 :)

Please see this for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestvalidationmode.aspx

and especially this article:

[ASP.NET 4 Breaking Changes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770147)

The basic difference is this:

2.0 - validation occurs only for asp.net pages

4.0 - validation occurs for every http request (services etc.)

Comment: Which is fine - but in the 4.0 way of doing things, there's no way to turn it off for an individual page where you could in 2.0 - which seems to be the main breaking change...

Comment: @Paul, the main change is the additional security layer. If you don't need it, it's fine. That's entirely up to you. I think this is the most important sentence from that article: "However, we recommend that you analyze any request validation errors to determine whether existing handlers, modules, or other custom code accesses potentially unsafe HTTP inputs that could be XSS attack vectors."